# date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface (Gravity Forms)

Tags: php, datediff, date-difference

Would love any help to this warning please.

```
    if ( $target_field->type == 'date' && $modifier2[0] == 'daysdifference' ) {
        $d2 = explode('/', $target_field4);
        $dates4 = $d2[2] . '-' . $d2[1] . '-' . $d2[0];
        $today = new DateTime();
        $datetime1 = date_create($dates4);
        $datetime2 = date_create();
        //$diff  = $today->diff( new DateTime( $dates4 ) );
        
        if($modifier2[1]){
            $d2 = explode('/', $target_field4);
            $dates4 = $d2[2] . '-' . $d2[1] . '-' . $d2[0]; 
            $d = explode('/', $target_field3);
            $dates3 = $d[2] . '-' . $d[1] . '-' . $d[0]; 
            
            //$diff  = $today->diff( new DateTime( $dates4 ) );
            $datetime1 = date_create($dates4);
            
            if($target_field3==''){
            $datetime2 = date_create();
            }else{
                $datetime2 = date_create($dates3);
            }
            
        }
        $diff = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
        $diffs = $diff->days;
        $value = $diffs;
        
    }

    return $value;
}
```

But I am getting this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, bool given
```

It's for a Gravity Form that compares a Date to either an 'other' date listed in the form, or if there is no 'other' date then it compares the date to today. The code is working great on the front end and also in the notification sent, but this error message is all through my error logs.

Would appreciate any help thank you!

Comment: _date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, bool given_ - `date_create` definition: `@return DateTime|false DateTime object on success or false on failure`. It seems you create invalid date strings that you pass into your `date_create` functions.

Comment: _expects parameter 1_ - indicates that you failed to create a valid `$datetime1` object

Comment: **$datetime1** is false because creation failed.  This would probably be because of the parameter you passed to it.  Do an echo on it to see that it is valid.